# Mongoose insert only Id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose only inserts Id's in my database. If I debug my code product_data is filled in, but Product is empty. how is that possible?.

```
var ProductSchema = require('./../models/productSchema');
var Products = mongoose.model('Product',ProductSchema);
[...]
    for(var i=1; i<result.length;++i){
      var product_data = {
          CNK : "TODO",
        EAN : "TODO",
        name : {nameNL: result[i]["product_name"], nameFR: "TODO"},
      [...]
         }
        Product = new Products(product_data);
        console.log(Product);
        Product.save(onInsert(err));
}
```

productschema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    CNK:String,
    EAN:String,
    name:{nameNL:String,nameFR:String},
   [...]
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you post any document you get before `Product.Save`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used  Products.collection.insert instead of save. works like a charm.